# Electron Squirrel Auto Updater The remote server returned an error: (308) Permanent Redirect

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, electron-packager, squirrel.windows

I was trying to make an auto-updater for my electron app and used [Hazel](https://github.com/Vercel/hazel/) as the update server, but when I tried this and tested it, following every step on the [electron guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/updates), It would always give me these errors in the `Squirrel-CheckForUpdate.log` file:

```
[10/12/23 11:54:19] info: FileDownloader: Downloading url: https://cbsh-updater.vercel.app//update/win32/1.0.2/releases?id=bellschedoverlay&localversion=1.0.2&arch=amd64
[10/12/23 11:54:19] warn: IEnableLogger: Failed to download url: https://cbsh-updater.vercel.app//update/win32/1.0.2/releases?id=bellschedoverlay&localversion=1.0.2&arch=amd64: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (308) Permanent Redirect.
```

```
[10/12/23 11:54:19] info: CheckForUpdateImpl: Download resulted in WebException (returning blank release list): System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (308) Permanent Redirect.
```

```
[10/12/23 11:54:19] fatal: Finished with unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (308) Permanent Redirect.
```

These errors come with stacktraces in between, which is why I separated them.

Here is my code:

```ts
function checkForUpdates() {
  if (app.isPackaged){
    const server = config.hazelUpdateURL;
    const url = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`;

    autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url });

    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
    
  }
}


autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {

dialog.showMessageBox({
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Restart', 'Later'],
    title: 'Application Update',
    message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
    detail:
      'A new version of the Crooms Bell Schedule has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.'
  }).then((returnValue) => {
    if (returnValue.response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()
  });

})

autoUpdater.on('error', (message) => {
  console.error('There was a problem updating the application');
  console.error(message);
});

checkForUpdates();
```

I tried the url it failed to download from in a browser, and it downloaded the RELEASES file successfully with the expected content, but does show a 308 status code in the networking tab of devtools.

How do I ignore this error and force it to download the RELEASES file even if it is a redirect?

Comment: Sounds like a question [for the Hazel folks at Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/hazel/issues)?

Comment: Maybe it is, but maybe it's not: the people who are most qualified to tell whether that 308 is their error or yours are the folks at Vercel. So even if you post here, just post on their issue tracker too, and at worst they tell you that you did something wrong and close the issue.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans alright, I'll make an issue.

Comment: (just make sure to search their issue tracker for 308, of course. Both the open and closed issues)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just checked for issues (open and closed) containing "308" and created an issue: https://github.com/vercel/hazel/issues/167.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this issue only happens on my main computer; all other computers I own just auto-update fine.